# Detect window width on the fly in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a template and it come with a jQuery function to detect the window width, but it only works if you open the window up or refresh the page, not when you adjust the window width.. From what IU have read I need to integrate the resize function into my codebase

```
$(window).resize(function()
```

but as my jQuery is limited I'm not sure how to put it in this script

```
var ww = $(window).width();

/* Menu */
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
$('body').find("#mainmenu li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("parent");
    }
});

$('body').find(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('body').find("#mainmenu").toggle();
});
adjustMenu();
});


 $(window).load(function () {
 $('body').find("#mainmenu").css('pointer-events', 'auto');
 });

var adjustMenu = function() {
"use strict";
if (ww < 900) {
    $('body').find(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
    if (!$('body').find(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
        $('body').find("#mainmenu").hide();
    } else {
        $('body').find("#mainmenu").show();
    }
    $('body').find("#mainmenu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $('body').find("#mainmenu li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click',  function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
    });
} 
else if (ww >= 900) {
    $('body').find(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
    $('body').find("#mainmenu").show();
    $('body').find("#mainmenu li").removeClass("hover");
    $('body').find("#mainmenu li a").unbind('click');
    $('body').find("#mainmenu li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).toggleClass('activelink');
    $(this).find("ul").toggleClass('animatedfast');
    $(this).find("ul").toggleClass('fadeInUp');
    });
    $('body').find("#mainmenu ul li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        $(this).find("ul li").toggleClass('animatedfast');
        $(this).find("ul li").toggleClass('fadeInLeft');
    });
  }
    };
```

I can see that the logic is taking place in the adjustMenu function, so would I wrap that in the resize function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious,  but why not pull the whole thing out of

```
$(document).ready ()
```

Place it in a function

```
Function  doAllOfThis (
//do everything
);
```

And then call it on document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function ({
    doAllOfThis();
});
$(widow).resize (function ({
    doAllOfThis();
});
```

I don't see anything that would be an issue.  But you could just extract the code with "if ww =" conditions and move that to a function,  then do as above with the function.

**BETTER SOLUTION**

Just noticed the

```
adjustMenu();
```

Function is already set for you, so add

```
$(window).resize(function({
    var ww = $(window).width();
    adjustMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the `resize` event.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var ww = $(window).width(); // will contain width after resize

    // your adjust logic here
});
```